# VoiceCommand Definition with Cortana Point in PhraseList Item

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

I want to create a Command, which can select a vehicle by voice. 
f.e.

> Hey Cortana, select Vehicle Audi A3 8P1 1.9 TDI

CommandDefinition:

```
Select Vehicle {BrandName} {ModelName} {SpecificType}.
```

Everything works fine till the last Position SpecificType **1.9 TDI**. When I say

> Hey Cortana, select Vehicle Audi A3 8P1 S3 Quattro

everything works fine.

I think, `Cortana` has a problem with dots inside a phraseitem.

Do you know one workaround which will work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue. I test the official sample with `1.9TDI`, it works well.  I spoken "point" for ".".

Comment: Can you please try it, what happens if you type it inside the Cortana field? 
If I type it with a Point (1.9) she brings me to bing search. if i type 1 Point 9 it works fine.